# MAX7219 (7-segment display) with Raspberry Zero W doesn´t work

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I tried everything I found but the display didn´t work. I connected the display and installed the libraries according to these instructions but still does not work.(https://max7219.readthedocs.io/en/0.2.3/)

Do not you know what could still be wrong? I have a LED connected to Raspberry, so if it is not enough to power the display yet, is it possible?

Once I hit Raspberry and the display turned on for a moment, then it went out. When I want to upload a python script, it does not respond at all and throws bugs with libraries.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: If you do not know how to put it into operation and everything you need to install.
I have a script in Python, which just does not run.
https://pastebin.com/id6EE69M